# ViewPager access inflated view items

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement ViewPager to combine two view within one activity, in which I'm facing NullPointerException when I'm trying to access items using findViewById in inflated views, my custom page adapter is as follows,

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

  @Override
  public int getCount() {

     return 2;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

     return view == ((View) object);
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(View view, int value, Object object) {

     ((ViewPager) view).removeView((View) object);
  }

  @Override
  public Parcelable saveState() {

     return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
           .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     int resultId = 0;         
     switch (position) {

        case 1:
           resultId = R.layout.layout2;
           break;

        case 0:
        default:
           resultId = R.layout.layout1;
           break;
     }
     View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resultId, null);
     ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

     return view;
  }
```

}

And my activity is as follows, in which I'm trying to access button which is inside layout1 which throws null value.

```
   public class PageSwiperActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.viewpagerlayout);

      Button myButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
   }
}
```

My viewpagerlayout.xml contains only,

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

and my layout1.xml contains one button. Give me some guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set your `PageAdapter` to `ViewPager`?
If you don't set it, then remove line with button and add this code to your activity:

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerLayout);
viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter());
```

instead of this

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

You can call `findViewById` to get your button in this method of your adapter:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    ... // your previous code
    final Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);

    return view;
}
```

after you have inflated layout which contains this button.

Answer (score 1):

After `setContentView(R.layout.viewpagerlayout);`

you are using

`Button myButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);` directly.

But actually **viewpagerlayout** doesn't have any view with id **myButton**.

So that you are getting **NULL Pointer Exception**. Before using **findViewById**, you have to add views to ViewPager layout.

In the code you posted here, it seem to be you are adding, but you have to use it after **setContentView**.

Comment: I guess I'm adding views in CustomPagerAdapter, how I've to initialise the Button after adding views?